# Product Zoom Effect WooCommerce

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to create a zoom effect like this http://jsfiddle.net/SWDhG/
But I'm trying to open the `<a href="imglink">` link not the `<img src="">` tag, so i need som help with jquery.

html:

```
<div class="images"> 
    <a href="http://us.123rf.com/400wm/400/400/teddy2007b/teddy2007b0903/
        teddy2007b0903‌​00008/4539531-cup-and-bouquet-of-flowers-decorative-floral-
       background-for-banner-‌​vector.jpg" class="zoom" title=""> 
     <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-BKBDFTVyTVs/TdmU9SuHU5I/AAAAAAAAASk/
      e7oUIN34cc4/s‌​320/blue+salvia.jpg" class="attachment-shop_single wp-post-image"/>
     </a>
 </div>
```

This is the original code

```
$(function() {
    $('li a').click(function() {
        $('div img').attr('src', $(this).find('img').attr('src'));
        $('div').show();
        return false;
    });

    $('div').mousemove(function(e){
        var h = $(this).find('img').height();
        var vptHeight = $(document).height();
        var y = -((h - vptHeight)/vptHeight) * e.pageY;

        $('div img').css('top', y + "px");
    });

    $('div').click(function(){
        $('div').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you post your html as well?

Comment: `<div class="images">
<a href="http://us.123rf.com/400wm/400/400/teddy2007b/teddy2007b0903/teddy2007b090300008/4539531-cup-and-bouquet-of-flowers-decorative-floral-background-for-banner-vector.jpg" class="zoom" title="">
    <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-BKBDFTVyTVs/TdmU9SuHU5I/AAAAAAAAASk/e7oUIN34cc4/s320/blue+salvia.jpg" class="attachment-shop_single wp-post-image"/></a>
</div>`

@zfrisch here!

Comment: Esster, please update the question with the HTML code, instead of posting it as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/SWDhG/36/

Here's a fiddle that does what you want.

```
   $(function() {
$('li a').click(function() {

//here's the change --> 
    $('div img').attr('src', $(this).attr('href'));
// we change the information we take from the element to the 
// href attribute of the element, $(this), which is assigned
// to the element that caused the event, the anchor tag
    $('div').show();
    return false;
});

$('div').mousemove(function(e){
    var h = $(this).find('img').height();
    var vptHeight = $(document).height();
    var y = -((h - vptHeight)/vptHeight) * e.pageY;

    $('div img').css('top', y + "px");
});

$('div').click(function(){
    $('div').hide();
});
});
```

I used my own demo image href attribute for the sake of brevity.

Comment: you can achieve - `$(this).find('img').parent().attr('href');` with just - `$(this).attr('href');`

Comment: @wahwahwah you're correct and it's obviously faster so I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To get the hyperlink address:

```
$('li a').click(function() {
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    // do something with it
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Ok, can you please create a jsfiddle with the full code of the zoom effect?

Comment: @Esster can you try to incorporate the helpful answer I've provided into a fiddle of your own? I'm happy to help you with any issues you may encounter.

Comment: @Esster I provided you with a fiddle because I think sometimes it helps to see to learn, but I agree with wahwahwah, you should definitely peek through and see what changes were made and what they did. Feel free to ask questions.